# Why is the Relation R3 Transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Given $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$

in the Relation $\mathcal{R} = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$

I understand why $\mathcal{R}$ is Reflexive, Symmetric

but why is it also transitive?

In my understanding for a relation to be transitive for this particular example it must have something like $(1, 2), (2,3), (1,3)$ to be transitive.

Comment: It is *vacuously* transitive.  **IF** (*and only if*) you can find a situation where $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are pairs in the relation while $(a,c)$ is *not* a pair in the relation will it be called "*not transitive*."  Since no such counterexample exists, that implies that it is indeed transitive.

Comment: The only possibilities for if $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ then $(a,c)$ are just verified for $a=b=c$ by definition of $R_3$ so it satisfy the property thus is transitive.

Answer (score 1):

It is transitive, but in a trivial way. One way to think about this is that there is no triplet that contradicts transitivity! Then by the excluded middle property ($P\land\neg P=True$) the relation is transitive.

You can also reason like this: Let $aRb$ and $bRc$. The. $a=b=c$, because of the properties of the relation. Then $aRc$.